# python selenium Scraper:Want to save the data into a json file?

Tags: python, json, selenium

I have created a scraper using selenium python.I have a website "http//:www.mytravelexp.com"for which i have created a scraper.
**Technology used**:python,selenium.
**Sample example of what I have achieved :**
I have used the scraper to get the links and images from a single webpage.I am getting the data in my console.
**What I need the result to be :**
I want the result to be saved into the json file in this format:
"link":"http://www.mytravelexp.com"
"image":"http://www.mytravelexp.com/image1"
Please suggest how to do.
Here is the code:

```js
index.py
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import re 
import json
   
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path="D:\Codeless_Events6\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.mytravelexp.com/")
sleep(3)
  
src = driver.page_source
print(driver.title)
 text_found = re.search(r'Learn More', src)
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a'):
    print(a.get_attribute('href'))
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span'):
 print(a.get_attribute('href'))
 images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
for image in images:
 print(image.get_attribute('data-src'))
sleep(4)
print(text_found)
dictionary ={
    "title":"",
    "link" :"",
    "button" :"",
    "image" :""
}
   
with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(dictionary, outfile)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my edit to your code according to my understanding of your requirements :

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import re
import json


driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=r"C:\Users\Atharva\Desktop\Projects\selenium\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.mytravelexp.com/")
sleep(3)

src = driver.page_source
print(driver.title)
entry = {}
count = 0
dictionary = {}

text_found = re.search(r'Learn More', src)
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a'):
    href = a.get_attribute('href')
    if href:
        entry['title'] = href
        entry['link'] = a.get_attribute('class')
    dictionary[count] = entry
    entry = {}
    count += 1
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span'):
    href = a.get_attribute('href')
    if href:
        entry['title'] = href
        entry['link'] = a.get_attribute('class')
    dictionary[count] = entry
    entry = {}
    count += 1
    images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')

for image in images:
    data_src= a.get_attribute('data-src')
    if data_src:
        entry['title'] = data_src
        entry['link'] = a.get_attribute('class')
    dictionary[count] = entry
    entry = {}
    count += 1

with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(dictionary, outfile)
driver.close()
```